# VMWare Workstation Pro 14 shared clipboard not working

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation, clipboard, ubuntu-18.04

I have a VMWare Workstation Pro 14.1.2 setup with a Windows 10 host and multiple Ubuntu 18.04 guests.  The shared clipboard does not work in any of the Ubuntu guests.  I tried reinstalling the Open VM Tools, pausing and restarting the VM, using a different VM, making a new VM, and even making a new VM with a different Ubuntu version.  None of those worked.

I have no clue why this is not working.  Does anyone else know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: For some reason, it seems to be working now.